# is there a way to use Arrays in this C problem?

Tags: arrays, c, digits

I am doing this problem:

"We have a huge decimal number N. Write a program to determine the followings:

```
The number of digits in N.
Is N an even number?
The number of zeros in it.
Is N a multiple of 11? Note that we can determine if N is a multiple of 11 by checking the difference between the sum of the odd positioned digits and the sum of the even positioned digits. For example, 82375 is not a multiple of 11 because the sum of the even positioned digits is 2 + 7 = 9, and the sum of the odd positioned digits is 8 + 3 + 5 = 16, and the difference between 9 and 16 is 7, which is not a multiple of 11.
```

We will give you the number one digit per line. For example, if you get digits ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’, ’4’, ‘0’ in order, then the number is 12340. The number will not start with 0.
Input Format

The input has several lines. Each line has a digit. EOF indicates the end of input.
Output Format

Output the four answers above line by line. If the number is even output a 1; otherwise a 0. If the number is a multiple of 11 output a 1; otherwise output a 0.
Subtask

```
10 points: you can store the decimal number in an integer without overflow
10 points: the number of digits is no more than 32768, so you can store digits in an array
80 points: you will get MLE if you use array"
```

my code is:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int digit(long n);
int is_even(int n);
int count_zeros(long n);
int is_multiple(long n);

int main() {

    int digits = 0;
    long x;

    scanf("%ld", &x);
    digit(x);
    int even = is_even(x);
    printf("%d\n", even);
    printf("%ld\n",count_zeros(x));
    printf("%ld\n", is_multiple(x));
}

int digit(long n)
{
    int digits = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        n /= 10;
        digits++;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", digits);
}

int is_even(int n)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;

}
int count_zeros(long n)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        n /= 10;
        if (n %10 == 0)
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}

int is_multiple(long n)
{
   if (n % 11 == 0) {
       return true;
   }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Basically i dont know how to meet the problem's requirement, so I made a simpler version of the problem. Any clue on how to do this?

If you comment on this, please be nice, I am a beginner and people was rude in the past,if you have nothing important to say, do not be mean/do not comment.

Comment: What you need to do is break down the problem in to smaller chunks, then when you're stuck with a really specific problem ask a question on Stack Overflow. You will have much more chance of help. Start with reading the input and put it into an array> read from input until you face EOF. Only then start the calculations with the input data you're given - you're on the right track for that but it would probably require a little refactoring when dealing with an array.

Comment: There is always a way to use arrays for any problem.  The more interesting question is whether it is possible to avoid arrays or any other data structure that takes a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first problem with your current version is it only reads one integer. However problem states that each digit is on a separate line. The first approach may be to just replace that scanf with a loop and keeping multiplying by 10 and accumulating until end of file. Then the rest of the program would work fine.

A more advanced approach will be to use an array to store the digits. An integer can hold a very limited number of digits whereas you are only bounded with the size of available memory using array.

So in the reading loop rather than storing digits in an integer, you can store digits in an array (which could be fixed size because an upper limit is given). But for the rest of the program you should change the calculation to use digits in the array instead of the regular integer arithmetic.

Comment: A yet more advanced approach would be to **not** use an array to store the digits. It could win you 80 points if I understand the subtasks correctly.